# u-boot stuck at starting kernel for zybo z7

Tags: fpga, xilinx, u-boot, l4re

I define the zynq.cc in l4/pkg/bootstrap/server/src/platform as

```
#elif PLATFORM_TYPE_zynq_zybo_z7
    switch (PLATFORM_UART_NR) {
      default:
      case 1: kuart.base_address = 0xe0001000; 
              break;
    };
```

This is my U-boot log

```
U-Boot 2018.09-00427-g4024652143-dirty (Sep 01 2023 - 17:07:44 +0200)
CPU:   Zynq 7z020
Silicon: v3.1
Model: Digilent Zybo Z7 board
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  ECC disabled 1 GiB
MMC:   sdhci@e0100000: 0
Loading Environment from SPI Flash... SF: Detected s25fl128s_64k with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB
OK
In:    serial@e0001000
Out:   serial@e0001000
Err:   serial@e0001000
Net:   ZYNQ GEM: e000b000, phyaddr 0, interface rgmii-id

Warning: ethernet@e000b000 (eth0) using random MAC address - 36:c7:49:3e:11:ce
eth0: ethernet@e000b000
Checking if uenvcmd is set ...
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
15130688 bytes read in 967 ms (14.9 MiB/s)
11258 bytes read in 14 ms (785.2 KiB/s)
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 03000000 ...
   Image Name:   L4 Image #30
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    15130624 Bytes = 14.4 MiB
   Load Address: 01000000
   Entry Point:  01000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 02a00000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x2a00000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 3eb2a000, end 3eb2fbf9 ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

I am working on running a L4Re L4Linux image on Zybo Z7-20.
I also defined my bootargs.
A normal Linux image runs fine on the Zybo but when I try to run the L4Image it gets stuck,
any clue how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance for any kind of advice or input :)

Comment: Try to bisect the problem by (a) enabling Linux kernel verbose boot decompression (CONFIG_DEBUG_LL, CONFIG_DEBUG_UNCOMPRESS and friends), and (b) enable EARLYCON or EARLY_PRINTK, which requires both kernel configuration (build-time) and kernel command line (boot-time) changes.